# Retrieving session ID value from a JSF request

Tags: java, session, jsf

How do I retrieve the session ID value inside a JSF managed bean?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
FacesContext fCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fCtx.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
String sessionId = session.getId();
```

Comment: I was just about to answer with almost the exact same code :)

Answer (score 1):

You try

```
{
String uuidFc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionId(true);
}
```

This line return the facesContext sessionId value

Comment: This returns the servletcontext sessionid. And how does it differ from the other accepted answer? The true? Then why should be added to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [OmniFaces JSF utility library](https://omnifaces.org/).

```
String sessionId = Faces.getSessionId();
```

Adding this as an answer, since it's highly likely that you will use this library, if you use JSF.